# ssh: connect to host 4.12.678.96 port 22: Operation timed out

Tags: ssh

I'm new to AWS I am trying to ssh into my ec2 instance and got above error. Tried checking UFW status and got sudo: ufw: command not found. I knows it's probably quite straightforward but can anyone help pls.

Comment: The 678 in there meants that's definitely not a valid IP address; each component will always be between 0 and 255, so I'd guess you've entered an incorrect address somewhere.

Comment: @TomRevell when the IP is out of range, my `openssh-client` tries to resolve the given argument as a hostname instead and the error message results in `Name or service not known`, and on MacOS the resulting message is `nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

Comment: Apologies I purposely didn't  put the correct IP address. So I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Are there any other possibilities?

Comment: Maybe the port is set to something other for security purpose? Provide more information: ping, traceroute, screenshots etc

Comment: Is the security group allowing traffic on port 22 coming from the public ip address you're connecting from?